# How would I make a mesh (of just the empty spaces not anything else) of another mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make the opposite of a honeycomb mesh, I would like to have just hexagons with empty space in-between them (the mesh I'm working on) [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the <kbd>Add Mesh:</kbd><kbd>Extra Objects</kbd> addon via <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Addons</kbd>.
[image]

Add a honeycomb
[image]
and set the number of rows and columns as required.
[image]
In <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and <kbd>F</kbd> to fill. Then select one of the hexagons and use <kbd>Select</kbd> > <kbd>Similar</kbd> > <kbd>Area</kbd> to select the rest.
[image]

Then <kbd>CTRL-I</kbd> to invert the selection and <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the frames giving the final result below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made just one of the hexagons and then used array modifiers to duplicate it (with the desired gap in-between) and that worked just fine.

Comment: You could have used the built-in Extra mesh Objects addon, add a Honeycomb and set the number of rows and columns on the lower left settings dialog. In Edit mode, select all and 'F' to fill, then select one of the hexagons and use the Select > Similar > Area to select the rest. Then CTRL-I to invert the selection and X - delete to delete the frames. - Took much longer to type than it would to do it in Blender! :^)

Comment: oh! thanks, that would've been a lot faster XD

Comment: Just for completeness I've added my solution as an answer below.